# Replacement motherboard for an HP Pavilion P6-2280EA

Tags: motherboard

my dad's computer broke recently and when he took it in for repair the guy said it was the motherboard and it was going to cost hundreds of pounds to get a replacement. It is an HP Pavillion P6-2280EA system a few years old.

I told him (perhaps a little overconfidently) that i could replace it much cheaper no problem. Now [i have looked at the spec](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c03381123) i am not so sure.

I am not that familiar with the uATX form factor. Isn't it pretty much the same thing as mATX or am i way off?

Can anyone recommend a decent and not too pricey replacement for [this mobo](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-c03135925)?

[This one looks pretty similar](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/122134011446?_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) to me. Any thoughts on whether it would be a match?

Thanks

Comment: The question is actually very specific, because the build HP has it in requires an mATX motherboard capable of acting as a mBATX motherboard - that is, they put it on the "wrong" side of the case. Moreover, HP doesn't supply "normal" power cable assemblies for the front button or (sometimes) the ATX power suppy itself, so there are in fact very few (perhaps only one) answers. For that reason, the question is not too broad.

Comment: Thanks for your support, i don't really know how the question could of been any more specific.

Comment: Do you plan on installing Windows from scratch? because swapping out a motherboard for a completely different model is going to make things worse believe it or not so I would recommend replacing it with an [exact match](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-shipping-for-HP-desktop-Motherboard-for-Joshua-H-JOSHUA-H61-uATX-Mainboard-670960-001-Intel/763022020.html) unless you are comfortable with [Windows SYSPREP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: I was just gonna re-install Windows to be honest. You see any reason why the linked board above wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1):

On Ebay(usa) the motherboard in question is listed from $150(us) and up.

From what I've read on the wikipedia page on microATX [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroATX)  µATX, mATX, and uATX are the same thing.  Possibly the HP boards may be a little of the standard microATX specs.

At the time I am writing this the exchange rate for USD to British Pound is $1USD = .77Pound.  So it may be around 115 Pounds for the board.  Not sure what the guy is charging for labor.

What would be really good to know is information on the chassis/case.  HP used to be all proprietary and have chassis/cases you could not put just any board in.

There are other things to note however.  As stated in the following link, some manufacturers use custom front panel connections that you may have to modify to use with an off the shelf board.  [aforementioned link](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/303250-31-pavillion-case-build-desk)

Hope this helps, even if is not the answer you were looking for.